# Loading AvalonEdit syntax highlighting definitions from resource

Tags: wpf, avalonedit

I have an AvalonEdit text box, and I want to include syntax highlighting. I've already created my .xshd file, and I have it in my project as a Resource. Now how do I apply it to my AvalonEdit box?

I've looked through a bunch of tutorials, but none of them have the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:

```
System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.FileName.xshd"));
```

Comment: I get "NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized."

Answer (score 1):

Another way, that worked for me:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(WpfApp15.Properties.Resources.sql))
    {
        using (var reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(stream))
        {
            this.AvalonQuery.SyntaxHighlighting =
                ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Highlighting.Xshd.HighlightingLoader.Load(reader,
                    ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Highlighting.HighlightingManager.Instance);
        }
    }
```

You need to change `WpfApp15` and `sql`.

I've used `Project` `>` `... Properties` `>` `Resources` `>` `Add Resource` `>` `Add Existing File...`.